# My python code is not running. It gives me an error below

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python (humanities background). This is my first attempt.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
plot = sns.boxplot( 
    data=df, 
    width=0.5,
    showmeans=True
)

plot.set(xticklabels = ['PRE', 'POST'] , ylabel='CAT score \n(0 to 40)' , title='some title')
plt.show()
```

But it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\Admin>& C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/box_and_whiskers.py
& was unexpected at this time.
```

[This is the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUx29.png)

Comment: You should try something simpler for your first attempt.

Comment: how do you run your program? are you using an IDE?

Comment: This is not exactly a python error. Can you describe how you are trying to run the code? Are you using the command prompt? If so I'd recommend you to download winpython or anaconda, and use spyder.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code.

The code was written by my friend. I am just trying to run it. I installed pip, pandas, matplotlib and seaborn. But when I press the "green-run" button, it just gives me that error.

What does that mean? Could it be something to do with the cvs dataset?

Comment: it looks like problem with `Visual Studio Code` - maybe mistake in settings. And it has nothing to do with dataset. Run it normally in cmd.exe without `&` and it should work. `C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Admin/Downloads/box_and_whiskers.py`

Comment: @RahmaAltaf, This doesn't look like a python issue. Can you check the my_data.csv file for any malformed data.

Comment: So, I don't have the dataset on me. As in I didnt really do anything to it. My friend sent the code in python format and I just opened it.

Am I supposed to reload the dataset again?

Comment: @RahmaAltaf, It is not about reloading dataset, but to check whether the current dataset has any malformed row entry. Can you share the data set ? or you can read a step by step help https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/03/how-to-make-boxplots-in-python-with-pandas-and-seaborn/

Comment: I have added the dataset. please check

Comment: UPDATE: there was something wrong with the location of the files. i shifted it all to desktop in one neat folder. now the code works. hehe. thanks all